# Securely Storing Sensitive Data from App on Remote Server

Tags: android, security, encryption

I have an Android App where a user enters some sensitive information in the form of text. I need to store this data on a remote server, to be retrieved by that user from a different device. I want to secure this data against everyone other than that user, especially a rogue database admin - the user should be the only one capable of recovering the information.

My approach is, SALT will be generate in Android app and every sensitive data will be hashed with this SALT and will be stored for later decryption to get the actual raw data.

Is this the correct approach? or Any better approach for this?

If yes,

1. What if the user change the device?
2. How to use the same SALT in the new device as SALT cannot be saved in database?

**Update:** Sensitive data needs to be stored in Firebase Database.

Comment: what about [sqlcipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher).and store password on server

Comment: @sanemars, Thanks!, I want to store data in a cloud based database and I am not using the embedded database.

Comment: I thought typical use of salt was to prevent time-memory tradeoff by attacker when attempting to break a database of hashed passwords? Don't you want key stretching in this case, to defend against sub-par passwords? And you say sensitive data will be hashed with salt, but hashing is typically irreversible, sooo.... ?

Comment: @user69513, Yes, I want the sensitive data back as RAW text and I missed that it is irreversible. Is there any alternative approach for this? And what is key stretching?

Comment: See [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for one particular example. It's just a fancy term for making the password more computationally expensive to test, which hurts your user a tiny bit but a brute force attacker a lot.

Comment: I think salt might not be of much use here, it protects against rainbow tables and testing multiple passwords at once when an attacker gets their hands on a massive database table with all the hashed passwords for a site or service. If the password (or its hash) are never actually stored though, just used to decrypt data, I'm not seeing what you gain by it.

Comment: @user69513, I am confused, I am not good in these encryption terminologies. Basically I want to store some sensitive data and want to retrieve it back. These data needs to be protected with some key from app side and so even database administrator must not see these encrypted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

I'm not a security professional. I'm not an expert. I'm just some random developer on the internet who's done some reading in the past and took a stab at answering your question. Head over to the [information security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) if you want more reliable information.

---

A user enters sensitive information into your program. You want them to be able to recover it later, so you must save it somewhere. How to handle this?

Where to save it?

- On the device if it doesn't need to be accessible from elsewhere.
- On a server if the user might need to access it from a different device (or recover it).

How to secure it?

- Encrypt it.

What to encrypt it with?

- A standard, secure algorithm (such as AES), and a key derived from a user provided password.

But users tend to come up with poor passwords. If we're sending this to a server, and the database might be compromised, how to protect against brute force attacks?

- Employ a key stretching algorithm, such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

How secure is this, really?

- Well if the user picks a poor password, and then your database is compromised, brute force will be relatively easy.
- If the password ever leaves their device (like if you, say, reused the same password for the app to log in to your servers or something) then you're treading in dangerous waters.

Comment: Could you please this a bit more? "and a key derived from a user provided password."

Comment: Well if you aren't using key stretching, then I suppose you might simply run their provided password through a hash function such as SHA3 to get a suitable key for AES. If you're using (for example) PBKDF2, then it does that for you - you put their provided password in, and a key comes out.

Comment: But this doesn't decrypt the hashed password back right? Instead it wil again encrypt the password to hash and compare it with existing hash for match right?

Comment: There is no hashed password in this scenario. This isn't authentication, this is [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). The original data is encrypted with the key. This results in what looks like noise. It is then only recoverable from this "noise" if you have the original key (or guess it correctly, I suppose).